Problem with custom MIPI DSI display with Orange 3b RK3566
I’m trying to get a DSI display to work with a Orange 3b board with RK3566.
My display uses the Sitronix ST7701 driver.
I added the driver to the kernel and wrote the necessary device tree sources (DTS).
However, I’m running into some issues, and the console is showing the following errors.
Code:
*ERROR* Failed to find panel or bridge: -19
Could you help me identify the mistakes in my DTS?
Code:
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    fragment@0 {
        target = <&dsi1>;

        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";

            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            port {
                dsi1_out_port: endpoint {
                    remote-endpoint = <&panel_dsi_in>;
                };
            };

            st7701:st7701@0 {
                compatible    = "techstar,ts8550b";
                reg = <0x0>;
                status = "okay";
                reset-gpios = <&gpio1 24 0>; 


           

                port {
                    panel_dsi_in: endpoint {
                        remote-endpoint = <&dsi1_out_port>;
                    };
                };
            };
        };
    };

     fragment@1 {
        target = <0xffffffff>;

        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
        };
     };

    fragment@2 {
        target = <0xffffffff>;

        __overlay__ {
            status = "disabled";
        };
    };

    fragment@3 {
        target = <0xffffffff>;

        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
        };
    };

    fragment@4 {
        target = <0xffffffff>;

        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
        };
    };

    fragment@5 {
        target = <0xffffffff>;

        __overlay__ {
            status = "disabled";
        };
    };

    __fixups__ {
        video_phy1 = "/fragment@1:target:0";
        dsi1_in_vp0 = "/fragment@2:target:0";
        dsi1_in_vp1 = "/fragment@3:target:0";
        route_dsi1 = "/fragment@4:target:0";
        hdmi = "/fragment@5:target:0";
    };
    
    
};

and why can I compile only if I write like this, but if I write the name right away I get a compilation error.
Code:
fragment@1 {
        target = <0xffffffff>;

I also get a compilation error if I write, for example,
#include <dt-bindings/pinctrl/rockchip.h>

I compile with the command
dtc -@ -I dts -O dtb -o rk356x-4inch-screen.dtbo rk356x-4inch-screen.dts

